# Use %/% within a pipe

Tags: r, lubridate

I would like to get interval in days as an integer between two dates:

library(tidyverse) # esp for lubridate

```
date1 <- ymd('2022-01-01')
date2 <- ymd('2022-01-10')
day_interval <- interval(date1, date2)
day_interval %/% days() # returns 9
```

But I want to combine the 2 last lines into one. Is this possible? Tried e.g:

```
day_interval <- interval(date1, date2) |> %/% days()
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "day_interval <- interval(date1, date2) |> %/%"
```

How can I do the whole think in a oner using a pipe?

Comment: why not just use `interval(date1, date2) %/% days()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use

```
interval(date1, date2) %/% days() 
[1] 9
```

Or may also use

```
interval(date1, date2) %>% 
  `%/%`(., days())
[1] 9
```

Or with `|>`

```
interval(date1, date2) |> 
   {\(x) x %/% days()}()
[1] 9
```

Or using `%>%`

```
interval(date1, date2) %>%
   {. %/% days()}
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the pipe like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
date1 <- ymd('2022-01-01')
date2 <- ymd('2022-01-10')
day_interval <- interval(date1, date2) %/% days()
day_interval
#> [1] 9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Different option is using `difftime`:

```r
library(lubridate)
date1 <- ymd('2022-01-01')
date2 <- ymd('2022-01-10')
difftime(date1 ,date2 , units = c("days"))
#> Time difference of -9 days
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>